# How to restart PostgreSQL installed by Brew in OSX?

Tags: homebrew, postgresql

In Linux, it can be done by `/etc/init.d/postgresql-9.2 restart`. 
My OSX is not a server app.

I think it it can be done by `ALTER USER postgres with password '1234';` postgreQSL prompt but I am not sure if it is the meant way.

How can you restart the PostgreSQL server in OSX?

Comment: Are you using the OS X Server.app?

Comment: How did you install PostgreSQL? There are multiple ways and each may be subtly different.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Manually Start PostgreSQL:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

### Manually Stop PostgreSQL:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast
```

This [stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975556/how-to-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x) really goes into some great detail, with many more options.  I used it to create an alias to just run:

```
postgresql.server stop
postgresql.server start
```

Comment: This alias does the trick: `alias postgresql.server='function pgsql_server() { case $1 in "start") echo "Trying to start PostgreSQL..."; pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start ;; "stop") echo "Trying to stop PostgreSQL..."; pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast ;; esac }; pgsql_server'`
Commands:  ***postgresql.server start*** or ***postgresql.server stop***

Answer (score 119):

Brew has that covered:

```
brew services restart postgresql
```

Comment: I just updated my Postgres via brews (uninstalling the old one), but now Postgresql starts with the yellow color (status unknown). Because of that I can't connect to it Any ideas?

Comment: @MatheusFelipe I suggest to post a dedicated question

Answer (score 2):

I'm on a [brew install postgresql@9.6](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304024/how-do-you-install-an-older-version-of-postgres-9-6-using-homebrew) for legacy reasons, and actually needed to:

```
# First, close all connections, e.g. application servers and psql connections, then
brew services stop postgres
killall postgres
brew services start postgres
```