# How do you install an older version of Postgres (9.6) using homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, postgresql

Homebrew's current version of Postgres is 10 when installed with:

```
brew install postgres
```

How do I install an older version of postgres? Specifically 9.6

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can find available versions to install using `brew search`:

```
$ brew search postgresql
==> Searching local taps...
postgresql        postgresql@9.4        postgresql@9.5        postgresql@9.6
```

To install one of these older versions, pass the full name into `brew install`:

```
$ brew install postgresql@9.6
```

It will give you instructions on how to add that PATH of that particular version to your bash environment, so you can use its `psql` etc.

If you still have `psql` booting up a newer version of postgresql, try this:

```
brew install postgres@9.6
cp -rf /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.9 /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/.
brew switch postgres 9.6.9
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that.  Is 9.6 not available as a named version yet?  It only has 9.4 and 9.5 listed.

Comment: As of today, 9.6 is available.

Comment: Pinging @JK. for Nate's comment, have edited answer

Comment: This did install, but I still have no `psql` commands, and `libpq-fe.h` library available

Comment: same here, I can't manage to find the binary to add it to the path

Comment: As of writing (1.6.1), doing `brew install postgresql@9.6` seems to work, but if you attempt `brew info postgresql` still points to 10.3 (current stable). Doing `brew info postgresql@9.6` *looks* like it works, but one cannot `brew switch` to it. Still not sure yet how one resolves that.

Comment: Well, this MIGHT work, still getting through it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48096389/297472

Comment: My work around `brew install postgres@9.6; cp -rf /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.9 /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/.; brew switch postgres 9.6.9`

Comment: @Adi Thanks for your edit, though I’m not sure I fully understand it. Can you explain a little more about why that works? Could a symlink be used instead of copying the files?

Comment: @marneborn Your comment was edited into my answer by Adi, perhaps you can help answer the questions in my comment above?

Comment: `brew switch` is the "old way" to handle versions, these days it's by leaving it there and modifying your PATH, see the instructions after installation of a particular version...

Comment: At the end I had to also run `rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres && initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8`